# How to specify order of template loading in Django?

Tags: django, templates

So I have upgraded an old project from Django 1.6 to 1.10, and now all templatse from a specific directory are no longer loading.

the location of these templates are in

```
/project/templates/userena
```

these templates should be overriding the templates included with the userena library in

```
/usr/local/bin/python2.7/dist-packages/userena
```

I have read the Django documentation for template loading but it does not make sense to me at all.

Currently my settings.py has this

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
                        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
                ],
        'APP_DIRS': False,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'debug': DEBUG,
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
            'loaders': [
                'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
                'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

What do I need to change in my settings.py in order to have Django load templates from /project/templates/userena?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Django uses the template loaders in order according to the 'loaders' option. It uses each loader until a loader finds a match. ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/api/#loader-types)).

So, yes, ordering matters.

Comment: Well I don't even know what both of the loaders I'm using does exactly, I guess I will just try to switch the order and see if it works.

Comment: Sorry for the brevity. The first loader is searching in all directories specified in the `'DIRS'` key of the dictionary. The second one, in all apps that you have installed in your project. In your particular case, it's actually a bit trickier, since you have the same name for both the app and the local templates directory. I'm not sure, but it should work with your current ordering, since the filesystem loader is the one looking for in `project/templates/userena`. Can you maybe update your post with the template rendering?

Comment: I left all template settings the same, but I switched the order of my INSTALLED_APPS, and now the templates load correctly.